# getting maximum value of a varchar column in database

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i get the maximum value of my column that is a varchar with these values

for example i have a fieldname of myid which is varchar and what i want is to get the maximum value of the myid field . How can i query to get the 1-10 value of myid column?

```
myid
1-1
1-2
1-3
1-4
1-5
1-6
1-7
1-8
1-10
1-9
```

Comment: 1-10 is not the maximum string value, for 1 (the first character of the 10) is a smaller value than 2 in 1-2 for instance. In your head you are splitting the string into two numeric values and order by first one, then second. You can do the same with string funtions in SQL, but I'd recommend not to store the values as strings in the first place. If you are interested in the separate numeric values then store them as two separate numeric columns and not as one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using this trick:

```
order by length(myid) desc, myid desc
```

This will work for the data in the question.  A more general answer is:

```
order by substring_index(myid, '-', 1) + 0, substring_index(myid, '-', -1) + 0
```

Comment: @JcJohn . . . I have no idea what your question means.  This question and answer have nothing to do with auto incremented columns.

Comment: hello sir.. sorry. correct me if i got wrong or if this is bad query. I am making for primary key to stop duplicate by getting the last and increment it in php. Is this correct?  SELECT tbl_check_up.check_up_id FROM tbl_check_up ORDER BY substring_index(tbl_check_up.check_up_id, '-', 1) + 0, 
                    substring_index(tbl_check_up.check_up_id, '-', -1) + 0 DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @JcJohn . . . That looks like it will return the largest value.  If you are constructing the string, though, why not just zero pad the numbers, so you can use a simple sort?

Comment: what do you mean sir? i am a beginner. how can i do that? is my query work if it has only (1-* ) one digit or (1-***) to return the largest?

Comment: @JcJohn . . . Values like `'1-00001'` will sort properly.  You can create them using `lpad()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

Comment: hello sir. what if i got (**-1). or (***-1) three digit in the first but i only want is to increment the (1 - ***) right side of it

Answer (score 1):

For the data you've shown:

```
select myid
from data_table
order by cast(substr(myid, 3, 2) as int) desc
limit 1;
```

In this case the ordering function is the integer value of the portion of the identifier following the dash.  In general--i.e., for different or more complex data--you simply need to determine what the appropriate odering function is.